# Python - How can i print a certian range of numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print a certian range of numbers from a list. For example print all the numbers from 2-10 in your list that you created.

This is what i have so far,

```
values = [1,3,5,10,11,12,15,52,78,99]

for i in range(2,6):
    print(i)
```

I dont know how to print the range in values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
values = [1,3,5,10,11,12,15,52,78,99]

for i in values:
    if i >= 2 and i <= 10:
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data isn't too large, you can simply do:

```
for i in values:
    if i in range(2,6):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise/"Pythonic" way is probably this:

```
values = [1,3,5,10,11,12,15,52,78,99]
for i in values[2:6]:
    print(i)
```

this prints from the index of 2 to 5 since python skips the last one.

output will be:

```
5
10
11
12
```

answering your question, to print the values from 2-10 will be:

```
values = [1,3,5,10,11,12,15,52,78,99]
for i in values[1:]:
    print(i)
```

since indexing in python start at 0, which means your '3' is actually in index 1.